# How do I convert user entered string dates into an Excel Format

Tags: vba, excel

If a user enters jan-1-2018 or January-1-2018, how would I write vba to convert that to 01/01/2018?

Comment: Where do they enter it? Try looking up the `VBA.Date` module members in the *Object Browser* (F2).

Comment: Excel's generally quite good at recognising date formats anyway. Why not just make the user re-enter anything it can't parse?

Comment: `DateSerial(Split(str, "-")(2), Month("1 " & Split(str, "-")(0)), Split(str, "-")(1))`  Where `str` is the date.

Comment: Rule of thumb, you'll want to treat `Date` values as *dates*; treating them as strings will cause lots of problems down the line. If Excel is recognizing the date as a `Date`, then what you want is to set that cell's `NumberFormat`, not "convert" the date into a string... assuming we're talking about a cell that contains a date. If it's a textbox, then we're looking at something else entirely. Care to [edit] your question to clarify exactly what you mean?

Answer (score 2):

If a1 cell is "jan-1-2018" then do like this

```
Sub test()
    Dim m As Date, d As String

    m = DateValue(Range("a1"))
    d = Format(m, "mm/dd/yyyy")
    MsgBox d
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Text to Columns, Fixed Width, Next, MDY, Finish.

[image]

In VBA as,

```
Option Explicit

Sub Macro4()
    With Worksheets("sheet1").Columns(1)
        .TextToColumns Destination:=.Cells(1), DataType:=xlFixedWidth, FieldInfo:=Array(0, 3)
        .NumberFormat = "m/d/yyyy"
    End With
End Sub
```